# GHC 8.8.4 cannot suggests adding hashable even though it is already added

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I wrote a program making use of the `Hashset` from the `unordered-containers` library. It works fine on my computer with GHC 9.2.4. For some reasons I'm trying to port it to GHC 8.8.4 as mentioned in the title. It mostly boils down to adding some language extensions.

I experience a strange problem though.

I have a function `powerset :: Hashable a => Set a -> [Set a]`.

When compiling I get the following error:

```
Could not deduce (hashable-1.3.0.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable
                          a)
        arising from a use of ‘makeSubset’
      from the context: Hashable a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   powerset :: forall a. Hashable a => Set a -> [Set a]
        at Automaton.hs:48:1-45
      Possible fix:
        add (hashable-1.3.0.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable
               a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            powerset :: forall a. Hashable a => Set a -> [Set a]
    • In the first argument of ‘Set.foldr’, namely ‘makeSubset’
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
...
```

as you can see the compiler asks me to add hashability as a constraint to this function even though I already have it included. Do you know what can be the problem?

I compile with `ghc -Wall` and I have installed libraries the following way:

```
cabal install --lib unordered-containers
cabal install --lib hashable
```

One solution would be to follow their advice with this strange constraint, ghci seems to confirm this:

```
Prelude Set> :t Set.map
Set.map
  :: (hashable-1.3.0.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable b, Eq b) =>
     (a -> b) -> Set.HashSet a -> Set.HashSet b
Prelude Set>
```

As I said there was no problem on my computer with this setup and I do not know what is causing this.

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler starts showing you messages like these that refer both to simply `Hashable` and also `hashable-1.3.0.0:Data.Hashable.Class.Hashable` it means you got yourself into a situation where two different versions of a package have ended up in the dependency tree. Your `unordered-containers` has been built against `hashable-1.3.0.0` but the one you're directly depending on and that the `powerset :: Hashable a => ...` signature refers to is different, presumably newer. This happened because when you ran

```
cabal install --lib hashable
```

Cabal had no indication that you wanted this `hashable` to be usable together with the already installed `unordered-containers`, so it installed the newest version available and made that one visible to GHCi.

In this specific case you could have avoided the errors by simply not installing `hashable` explicitly, or alternatively hard-constraining the version. But that gets messy quickly, and it's pretty much defeating the point of using a package manager in the first place.

There's a much better way to avoid these sorts of problems: **never use `cabal install --lib`**. Instead, list the dependencies in a `.cabal` file for your project and just run `cabal build` / `cabal repl`, this way it can make sure to provide package versions that actually fit together and hide everything that would cause conflicts.

Comment: 100%. Maintaining a mutable global environment of available libraries in a consistent state is **much more** work than writing a small cabal file for each project. If you're installing different things at different times you can't just name the packages you want, the tool needs far more information about what you wanted for it to know whether to install a non-latest version, upgrade existing things, refuse to install, or install incompatible things alongside each other. In a cabal file you *can* just name the packages you want and everything just works (unless they genuinely conflict).